# Setting valid input types in Python Toolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, parameters, python-toolbox

When adding a python script tool to ArcToolbox, you can specify valid input types using the dropdown "Data Types" on the parameters tab in the tool properties.

[image]

In Python Toolboxes you can set these input types using the `datatype` property in the Parameters function. eg `datatype = "DEWorkspace"`

> ```py
> def getParameterInfo(self):
>     param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
>         displayName="Input workspace",
>         name="in_workspace",
>         datatype="DEWorkspace",
>         parameterType="Required",
>         direction="Input")
> ```

Both of these options seem to work OK when setting up the script.

Unfortunately, while in the script tool properties I have the option of a data type called "Workspace and Feature Dataset" (seen in the screenshot above), this option doesn't exist as a data type in Python Toolboxes.  So I found that it is possible to set multiple valid data types, called "Composite Data types." eg `datatype = ["DEWorkspace","DEFeatureDataset"]`

> ```py
> def getParameterInfo(self):
>     param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
>         displayName="Input Raster Dataset",
>         name="in_rasterdataset",
>         datatype=["DERasterDataset", "DERasterCatalog"],
>         parameterType="Required",
>         direction="Input")
> ```

However, I have found that any time I set a composite data type in my python toolboxes, there is no restriction enforced, so I can add any input I want and run the tool (which will then fail as it's received the wrong input data type).  If I have only one data type specified I am restricted to adding or browsing to that one data type, but if I have two or more data types the restriction disappears altogether.  In the screenshot below you can see an image and a layer file, neither of which fits the definition of Workspace or Feature Dataset.

[image]

So what am I doing wrong when defining my composite data types?  How can I set my Python Toolbox tool to allow both Workspaces *and* Feature Datasets, but not allow other types of inputs?

My `getParameterInfo` function:

```py
def getParameterInfo(self):
    params = []
    # Input geodatabases and feature datasets parameter
    params.append(arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input Geodatabases and Feature Datasets",
        name="in_workspaces",
        datatype=["DEWorkspace", "DEFeatureDataset"],
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input",
        multiValue=True
    ))
    return params
```

---

Parameter function examples are from [Defining parameter data types in a Python toolbox - Esri ArcGIS Desktop Help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm)